# How do interpret the output of 'service --status-all'

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, status

The man page of the service command lists the --status-all option so that you can check the status of all running services.

However when I run the command the first column can contain -, ? or + e.g.

```
[ - ]  postfix
[ + ]  postgresql-8.4
[ ? ]  pppd-dns
```

Is there some place where I can find out the significance of the first column ?
I'm running ubuntu 10.10

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- `[?]` means the service status isn't known (the init file does not output a status)
- `[+]` means the service is running
- `[-]` means the service is not running

There is probably an authoritative source, but I got it from looking at the `/usr/sbin/service` script.

Comment: thanks, I didn't realise it was just a shell script